# setTimeout does not work - what is wrong ?

Tags: javascript

i need to work with setTimeout function but that function does not work.
First of all,

```
  Player.prototype.playByUrl = function (url) {
        this.object.data = url;
        return this.play();
    }
```

Above code is my function and i call it

```
window.onload = function () {
        player = new Player('playerObject');
        setTimeout(player.playByUrl($mp4Link),3000);
    }
```

However, in above code, setTimeout does not work why ?

Comment: Where do you define `$mp4Link`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` needs a `function`:

```
setTimeout(function(){player.playByUrl($mp4Link)},3000);
```

---

The way you were doing it was that it was executing `player.playByUrl($mp4Link)` immediately on the start of the script.

Comment: @MertMETİN Where do you define `$mp4Link`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a **function** or a **string**:

```
setTimeout(function(){
              player.playByUrl($mp4Link)
           },3000);
```

OR

```
setTimeout("player.playByUrl($mp4Link)",3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with setTimeout() where the function needed to be in quotes.
Try:

```
window.onload = function () {
    player = new Player('playerObject');
    setTimeout("player.playByUrl($mp4Link)",3000);
}
```